# Querying data with parameters using httpClient with Angular13

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm using Angular 13 and I can pull data with httpClient. But I want to pull data by sending parameter.

How can I do this by sending parameters like below?

**inventory.ts**

```
this.inventoryService.getInventoryAllList(this.page, this.pageSize).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      complete: () => {

      },
      error: (e) => {

      }
    });
```

**inventoryService.ts**

```
    getInventoryAllList(page: number, pageSize: number) {
      return this.httpClient
        .get<{data: InventoryModel[]}>(constants.GET_INVENTORY_LIST_URL+`/${page}/${pageSize}`)
        .pipe(retry(constants.HTTP_SERVICE_RETRY), catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

the parameters i want to send can change constantly so i want to send it as variable

categoryId, categoryId, brandId, model Id. I send these sometimes, sometimes; I am sending categoryId and categorySubId. Sometimes I send categoryId so I always send different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your parameters to the server as http query parameters.

I usually include in all my projects a function dynamically generates the query parameters string given a record of parameters.

```js
function buildQueryParameters<T extends Record<string, string | boolean | number | (string | boolean | number)[]>>(queryParameters?: T): string {
  if (!queryParameters) return '';

  const params = Object
    .entries(queryParameters)
    .filter(([, value]) => value != null)
    .flatMap(([param, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value
          .filter(v => v != null)
          .map(v => `${encodeURIComponent(param)}=${encodeURIComponent(String(v))}`)
      }

      return [`${encodeURIComponent(param)}=${encodeURIComponent(String(value))}`];
    });

  return params.length ? `?${params.join('&')}` : '';
}
```

In your service you can change the `getInventoryAllList` method signagure to accept your parameters and than generate the request URL accordingly:

```js
// Somewhere in your code
export type InventoryListParameters = {
  // Here you should specify all your parameters and parameters type to let typescript handle type checking for you

  // Example
  categoryId?: string;
  categorySubId?: string;
  brandId?: string;
  modelId?: string;
  anotherParameter?: number;

  // [...]
}
```

```js
getInventoryAllList(page: number, pageSize: number, parameters?: InventoryListParameters) {
  const resourceUrl = `/${page}/${pageSize}${buildQueryParameters(parameters)}`

  return this.httpClient
    .get<{data: InventoryModel[]}>(constants.GET_INVENTORY_LIST_URL + resourceUrl)
    .pipe(retry(constants.HTTP_SERVICE_RETRY), catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

You can than use this function as follows:

```js
// Somewhere in your component
this.inventoryService
  .getInventoryAllList(this.page, this.pageSize, {categoryId: 'my-category', categorySubId: 'sub-category-id'})
  .subscribe({
    next: (result) => console.log(result),
    error: (error) => console.error(error),
    complete: () => console.log('done')
  })
```

**Update**:

I've updated the `buildQueryParameters` to support 'multiple' values per parameter name (e.g. if you want to generate '?filter=1&filter=13' or something similar)

Comment: build Query Parameters how do I use this function. your example is very nice, but can I send the parameter from "this.inventoryService.getInventoryAllList(this.page, this.pageSize).subscribe"?

Comment: resourceUrl: /1/100?0=%5B&1=%7B&2=%22&3=c&4=a&5=t&6=e&7=g&8=o&9=r&10=y&11=I&12=d&13=%22&14=%3A&15=1&16=%7D&17=%5D    the way it looks.

Comment: You can than use the function like `getInventoryAllList(1, 100, {categoryId: 'test'}).subscribe(result => console.log(result))`, you should pass an object not a string as `parameters` to the `getInventoryAllList` function.
If you want to pass `categoryId` with value `test` to the server you pass an object like `{categoryId: 'test'}`.
If you want to pass `categoryId` and `categorySubId` you can pass an object like `{categoryId: 'test', categorySubId: 'another-value'}`